# large factored number addition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I have some large integers that I want to add.  The problem is, I can't even store them in a usual way.  I store their prime decompositions, since they are so large.  Here is one example of a product I want:

$2^{100}\cdot97^{300}+13^{50}\cdot17^{200}$

One thing I know, they have no common factors.  How do I add them, and save the result as a prime decomposition again?  I need an algorithm, that can avoid expanding the integers into 10 radix form.  To make it a math problem (and not an algorithm problem), does anyone know how to calculate the factors in the decomposition directly from the factors in the sum?  Also, if this is the wrong forum, please let me know in the comments the appropriate forum.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such algorithm or whatever method which can handle your problem in full generality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This number has $627$ digits, which is small for an arbitrary precision program.
A vanishingly small proportion of numbers like this do not have a factor of at least, say, $100$ digits. Your sum is probably in that class.  Sums of small powers are a poor way to store large numbers because most large numbers cannot be stored that way.

I don't think there is any way to calculate the factor decomposition of the sum from what you have.  It might even be prime.  Any arbitrary precision program can handle small numbers like this.  If I feed it to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20factor%202%5E100*97%5E300%2B13%5E50*17%5E200) I get the fact that the number has $627$ digits and that a partial factorization is
$$5^3×17729×21737×50221×9079945801×16441924501×269980701319081×1397886802598297673234594043519579352028658054947394866487636502506015815941812887266642090877085788431701291456010743473720785420046423436856120466425336965441750777517400799989328659843101703902332792720478140833462239869241240106006785458142390107793347098685251282065940839772545979646478677050049002607236158820818815906611239067665805873384741916310281844310798477993420772443148384106393452706286551901829163928497142254006017819919953919702562895678891182858220972336093353922116710032345881403814710715099124523636128153352090629908397114483871566968260206555482086069$$
(7 distinct prime factors, 1 distinct composite factor)
but it admits that the last factor is composite.  Alpha will happily give me all the digits if I want to store it that way.

Comment: Is partial factorization, just finding a subset of the factors of an integer?

Comment: It means that the last factor is composite, so it is not a full prime factorization.  Alpha was unable to factor the last number.  It knows it is composite, so it has probably done the Fermat test and found that.  See the first paragraph of my edited answer.

Comment: The large factor that it did find, actually helps me, since I now know I will not in general be able to store the results to the sums I want to perform.

Comment: I think the big point you are missing is that large numbers are mostly random.  There is no way to store them with fewer bits that just storing the digits.  Information theory will tell you that.  If you add two numbers of the form you are seeing you have selected a sample of the large numbers, but not one that doesn't have large factors.  You are very unlikely to be able to store the result in fewer bits than the binary, which is what the small power representation allows.

Comment: Milikan, that helped me.  I was lucky to have repeated small factors for the terms of the sum, but I think I see now that the chance of finding repeated small factors in the result is small (and therefore the chance of being able to store it in a more efficient way is small).